# Dynamically recode and append fields to dataframe/tibble using yaml

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

**GIVEN** I want to transform a series of variables using information contained in a yaml file
**AND** I have the contents of the yaml file loaded into memory as list
**WHEN** I go to apply the re-mapping using the `$responses` element of each entry in the yaml file
**THEN** I get a new `data.frame/tibble` with columns appended using the names & recodes in each field's map entry

Below is a single entry in the yaml file. The entry `health` corresponds to a column name in the original `data.frame`. The `text` field is irrelevant for this question. The `responses` field contains the re-mapping recipe.

```yaml
health:
    study_name: global_health
    text: Would you say your health in general is excellent, very good, good, fair, or poor
    responses: 
        1: Excellent
        2: Very good
        3: Good
        4: Fair
        5: Poor
```

Here is an example of the original data - just focusing on a single field as an example:

```
  health
1      1
2      3
3      1
4      2
5      2
6      4
```

What I would like in this case (though with many more variables) is the following:

```
  health global_health
1      1     Excellent
2      3          Good
3      1     Excellent
4      2     Very good
5      2     Very good
6      4          Fair
```

What I have got so far is the following:

```
data_map <- yaml::read_yaml(map_filepath)
study_cols <- names(data_map)
```

And I have been able to leverage this structure to ignore entries that do not have a populated `responses` field in the yaml file - using this as my means of tracking which columns need to be recoded and which do not.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create simple local function to identify which have "responses" that need recoding 
pluck_func <- function(x) !is.null(x$responses)

# create mask using the function
recode_cols_mask <- data_map %>%
    map(~pluck(., pluck_func)) %>% 
    unlist()

# Identify variables that need recoding
recode_names <- study_cols[recode_cols_mask]
```

Now, what I would like to do is to take the variables that exist in `recode_names` and apply the renaming map for only those variables. My guess is that there is some clever solution with `purrr`'s `map` family of functions. I just haven't been able to find the right combination of `map()` and `mutate()`. For completeness, below is an entry that would not be recoded and returned. Again the way this is determined is effectively `is.null(data_map[['ANALWT_C']][['responses']])` will evaluate to `TRUE`.

```yaml
ANALWT_C: 
    study_name: weights
    text: Case-level study weight based on Census estimates
```

Solutions do not need to be in `tidyverse` for what it is worth. Happy to use base `R`. I just tend to find `tidyverse` processing a little more readable.

**UPDATE**
Here is my current solution which I would love to simplify if I can. But if not I can live with this for the moment.

```
recode_func <- function(df, data_map, recode_names, study_names) {
    for(v in recode_names) {
        df[data_map[[v]][['study_name']]] <- factor(
            df[[v]], 
            levels = seq_along(data_map[[v]][['responses']]), 
            labels = data_map[[v]][['responses']] %>% unlist()
        )
    }
    
    for(v in setdiff(names(data_map), recode_names)) {
        df[data_map[[v]][['study_name']]] <- df[[v]]
    }
    
    study_df <- df[study_names]
    
    return(list(base_df = df, 
                study_df = study_df))
}
```

with `study_names` defined as:

```
get_study_names <- function(x) x[['study_name']]
study_names <- data_map %>%
    map(~pluck(., get_study_names)) %>% 
    unlist()
```

**RESOLVED**
My current implementation based on the accepted answer below:

```
#' Recodes dataframe using info pulled from the yaml file in the main function \code{create_study_datasets}
#' 
#' @param df target data.frame
#' 
#' @param data_map list read in from yaml file containing data renames and recoding recipes
#' 
#' @param recode_names a character vector of names derived from the data_map in pre-processing steps that take place in 
#' the parent function. These are the fields that need to be recoded in some fashion. 
#' 
#' @param study_names a character vectory of names derived from the data_map in pre-processing steps that take place in
#' the parent function. These are all of the fields that should be returned - whether they are recoded and renamed or 
#' just renamed according to the data_map. 
#' 
#' @seealso create_study_datasets  
helper_recode_func <- function(df, data_map, recode_names, study_names) {

        # Apply the recodes as appropriate from the data map
    df <- df %>% 
        imap_dfc(~ if (hasName(data_map, .y) && hasName(data_map[[.y]], "responses"))
            recode(.x, !!! data_map[[.y]][["responses"]])) %>% 
        setNames(map_chr(data_map, "study_name")[names(.)]) %>% 
        bind_cols(df, .)
    
    # Apply passthrough/name-change for variables that do not need recoding
    df <- df %>% 
        select_if((names(.) %in% setdiff(names(data_map), recode_names))) %>% 
        setNames(map_chr(data_map, "study_name")[names(.)]) %>% 
        bind_cols(df, .)

    study_df <- df[study_names]
    
    return(list(base_df = df, 
                study_df = study_df))
}
```

Which when executed returns the expected outputs for both variables that require recoding and those that do not:

```
   ANALWT_C   weights health global_health
1 1274.9937 1274.9937      1     Excellent
2  550.3692  550.3692      3          Good
3 6043.4082 6043.4082      1     Excellent
4  262.2439  262.2439      2     Very good
5 8354.2522 8354.2522      2     Very good
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f <- function(x) recode(x, !!! data_map[[cur_column()]][["responses"]])

df %>% 
  mutate(across(any_of(names(keep(data_map, hasName, "responses"))),
                f,
                .names = "{data_map[[.col]][[\"study_name\"]]}"))

#>   health global_health
#> 1      1     Excellent
#> 2      3          Good
#> 3      1     Excellent
#> 4      2     Very good
#> 5      2     Very good
#> 6      4          Fair
```

Variant:

```
df %>% 
  imap_dfc(~ if (hasName(data_map[[.y]], "responses"))
    recode(.x, !!! data_map[[.y]][["responses"]])) %>% 
  setNames(map_chr(data_map, "study_name")[names(.)]) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Updated my original post with an example of how I integrated your suggestion into my ultimate solution.